# Datagridviewcell in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-applications

I want to ask in windows form we write DataGridViewCell so what we write in web instead of DataGridViewCell

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        For Each celli As DataGridColumn In row.Cells
            Try
                pdfTable.AddCell(celli.Value.ToString())
            Catch
            End Try
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: How is this `C#`?

Comment: myy bad ... i edit

Answer (score 0):

You should try `DataGridColumn` instead of `DataGridViewCell`

Comment: when i use this shows an error in this .. celli.Value "value is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DatGridColumn"

Comment: @user123 can you tell me what is row in `row.Cells`